# how to build mingwrt 5.1-trunck branch source

Tags: build, mingw, mingw32

I want to build 'mingw-org-wsl 5.1- trunk branch' code to use mingwrt  5.1

https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/5.1-trunk/tree/

The official setup tool(mingw-get-setup.exe) does not yet support this library

How can I build and use it? Or should wait until released?

Thanks.

Comment: MinGW.org is moving all development to osdn.net: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/mingw-users/thread/5A6511BB.8090308%40users.sourceforge.net/#msg36198954

Comment: Prebuilt wsl-5.1 binaries (for gcc-6.3.0-mingw32) are already available for download: https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/p15587  For the time being, you will need to install them manually -- as you (almost) correctly note, mingw-get.exe does not yet support them ... accounting for the migration will take some time.  (FWIW, your reference to mingw-get-setup.exe is the flaw in your observation -- its sole purpose is to install mingw-get.exe, which is the official installer for all other MinGW.org packages).

Comment: If the SF mailman thread reference I posted earlier isn't working for you, (it isn't for me, from outside of the archive view itself), try https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/mingw-users/?viewmonth=201801 instead, and browse the last posting for the month of Jan-2018